# How to validate popup lov's data is changed or not in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

Currently I'm creating an application in Oracle Apex 5.0. In that, one of the page contains 7 `popup lov`'s (or select list) containing some default value which has been retrieved from more than 1 table of more than 1 `schemas`.

Now my task is to create and apply a validation which checks, at least one of the `popup lov`'s data has been changed (no matter if all changes) if not then throw an error.

I've created a procedure inside a package and raise an error inside it (also I've created a function which returns `boolean` value) but it doesn't work at all.

I've also created hidden items for each `popup lov` to check those independently but it didn't work.

So, I thought maybe it because return val of lov affects my data. So, I modified my package but it also won't work.

Here's my code sample:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE package body KPC_CA is


 function find_change ( t_per_id      KPCPAY.EMP_INF.per_id%type, 
                        shift1        KPCPAY.EMP_INF.shft1%type,
                        shift2        KPCPAY.EMP_INF.shft2%type,
                        shift3        KPCPAY.EMP_INF.shft3%type,
                        wklyoff       KPCPAY.EMP_INF.wklyoff%type,
                        sup_name      KPCPAY.EMP_INF.emp_name%type,
                        sup_token_no  KPCPAY.EMP_INF.r_emp_no%type,
                        loc_desc      KPCPAY.EMP_INF.loc_desc%type,
                        dept_name     KPCPAY.EMP_INF.dept_name%type,
                        sbu           KPCPAY.EMP_INF.sbu_id%type,
                        effective_date          date
                  ) return number as

                        t_shift1        KPCPAY.EMP_INF.shft1%type;
                        t_shift2        KPCPAY.EMP_INF.shft2%type;
                        t_shift3        KPCPAY.EMP_INF.shft3%type;
                        t_wklyoff       KPCPAY.EMP_INF.wklyoff%type;
                        t_sup_name      KPCPAY.EMP_INF.emp_name%type;
                        t_sup_token_no  KPCPAY.EMP_INF.r_emp_no%type;
                        t_location      KPCPAY.EMP_INF.loc_desc%type;
                        t_dept_name     KPCPAY.EMP_INF.dept_name%type;
                        t_sbu           KPCPAY.EMP_INF.sbu_id%type;


                        flag                      boolean := false;


 begin
     begin
         select shft1, shft2, shft3, wklyoff, loc_desc, r_emp_no, 
                dept_name into t_shift1, t_shift2, t_shift3, t_wklyoff, 
                t_location, t_sup_token_no, t_dept_name                                
         from KPCPAY.EMP_INF 
         where per_id = t_per_id;


         select emp_name into t_sup_name
         from KPCPAY.EMP_INF 
         where emp_no = (select r_emp_no 
                         from KPCPAY.EMP_INF 
                         where per_id = t_per_id);                      


         SELECT distinct(decode ( SUBSTR(ORGANIZATION_CODE, 1, 1), 
                                                             '1','CORP',
                                                              '2','ACD',
                                                              '3','TRM',
                                                              '4','ACR',
                                                              '5','RR',
                                                              '6','RRS'
                            )) "decode" into t_sbu
            from apps.org_organization_definitions 
            where ORGANIZATION_ID= (select sbu_id 
                            from kpcpay.emp_inf 
                            where per_id = t_per_id);

     end;


     begin

         if t_shift1 != shift1 then
             flag := true;
         end if;

         if t_shift2 != shift2 then
             flag := true;
         end if;

         if t_shift3 != shift3 then
             flag := true;
         end if;

         if t_wklyoff != wklyoff then
                flag := true;
         end if;

         if t_sup_token_no != sup_token_no then
              flag := true;
         end if;

         if t_sup_name != sup_name then
              flag := true;
         end if;

         if t_location != loc_desc then
               flag := true;
         end if;

         if t_dept_name != dept_name then
                flag := true;
         end if;

         if t_sbu != sbu then
               flag := true;
         end if;                

      end;


      if flag = true then
         return 1;
      else
        return 0;
          -- or raise_application_error
      end if;              

    end find_change;
    end KPC_CA;
```

Comment: When passing Select List's values to your procedure: did you make sure that their values are stored into session state? The simplest way to do that is to use a push button which **submits** the page, and create a process which runs when that button is pressed; that process should then call your procedure (or a function, whatever), passing items' values to it. A simple way to check what you're passing is to create a logging table and - from your procedure - perform INSERT into it. Do that via an autonomous transaction procedure and commit insert, so that you'd be able to see what's going on.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Note that when using `<angle brackets>` in posts here, you need to use inline formatting (using backticks), otherwise it will be understood to be HTML - which in most cases means it disappears. Please also proof-read your posts prior to publishing them. Thanks!

Comment: Ok thanks. @halfer I will remind it.

Comment: Ok @Littlefoot I will check it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue was resolved. Just re-importing the application did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, what I would do is the following:

1. Create your 7 popup LOVs, as you've already done. Call them, say, `P1_POPUP_1`, etc.
2. For each one of those, create a Hidden item, called `P1_POPUP_1_ORIG`, where the Source is the `P1_POPUP_x` item.
3. Then create a validation of type PL/SQL Expression, and the expression is:

.

```
:P1_POPUP_1 != :P1_POPUP_1_ORIG AND :P1_POPUP_2 != :P1_POPUP_2_ORIG ...
```

This works as long as you know the starting value and ending values will not be null. If you need to handle nulls, the expression would change a bit.

You could also change to different validations for each item, so you know which one the user did not change.

This way there is no complicated function that needs to be maintained.

**Edit**: 
There are multiple ways to handle null values. In this sort of case I usually do something like:

```
NVL( :P1_POPUP_1, '*' ) != NVL( :P1_POPUP_1_ORIG, '*' ) AND 
NVL( :P1_POPUP_2, '*' ) != NVL( :P1_POPUP_2_ORIG, '*' ) AND  ...
```

Here, I've chosen '*' as a simple string I know will never appear as an actual value, but you may want to choose something more appropriate for your expected values.

Comment: @ealson actually I did it before too, but it dosen't work, and yes I need to handle null values also.

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't a helpful description of the problem. I can't tell if you're getting an error, if invalid values pass as valid, or vice versa or what.

Comment: actually the problem is I'm not getting any error. but still this validation is not executing. Also conditions are not applied but still it's not getting executed. I will edit and repost this question to show you my validation code.

Comment: Then I would add calls to `apex_debug` at the beginning of your function to log the state of all those items, then run your page in debug mode. Start by reducing the validation to a single item, get that working, then add more. and when you say your validation is "not executing" do you mean it's not running at all (again, check the debug log), or running and saying it's valid?

Comment: Problem solved! I have deleted my application and imported a backup copy(I don't know why but many of them(copies) are also affected with same problem. this was the initial copy). And then I got result as I expected. But seriously this is not a proper solution. Right?

Comment: That is indeed strange. I can't really say what was happening without seeing the debug log before and after.

Comment: I don't know why but it happens again 4 days ago. And I spent a whole day again for searching the cause but I didn't found anything. So, agian I deleted my application and imported the backup copy and again the problem solved! And sorry I don't know where to find debug log, can you please tell me. So next time it will help me to find any clue.

Comment: When you are logged in as a developer, your page will have a toolbar at the bottom. Use the Debug button to go into debug mode (you can also do this in the URL) and then View Debug to see the logs for each page load.